# Updated to iMovie 10.1.6: Movies and projects missing

Tags: imovie

(MacOS: Sierra 10.12.1 , iMovie: 10.16)

UPDATE:
I see now I have TWO iMovie folders, one on my local drive (with some valid projects and movies) and another on my eternal drive (where everything was supposed to be).  With iMovie, I can only see the final movies only on my local drive. No Movies are found or visible that are on my eternal drive. So questions are:
1. I am simply unable to see, open, find ANY final movie via iMovie that resides on the external drive.  Where are my movies?  iMovie is really inconvenient to say the least.
2. How can I move/merge my local drive projects, folders, and etc into my external drive folder?

ORIGINAL:---------------
I am missing movies and projects once I update to 10.1.6. When I attempt import from standard folders, the individual clips are imported into the wrong events and other projects aren't showing anyway.  It seems every time I update iMovie a huge mess is left behind.  Any thoughts on how I can proceed?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK, it works properly after I uninstalled iMovie entirely and ran an 'app cleaner' to be sure and reinstalled. iMovie proceeded to properly recognize and import previous iMovie 10 and 9 versions.